# DeploymentException & Class Not Found on WebLogic Admin Server 11g

Tags: java, deployment, properties, weblogic, ear

> ***Related:*** [Load external properties files into EJB 3 app running on WebLogic 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6540693/load-external-properties-files-into-ejb-3-app-running-on-weblogic-11)

Using Oracle Enterprise Pack for Eclipse, I created an Enterprise Project and named it:

PropertiesDemoEAR

Also created a PropertiesDemoEARWeb module in which I put this code

(inside PropertiesDemoEARWeb / Java Resources / src / com.project.util):

```
package com.project.util;

public class PropertiesFileHandler extends ApplicationLifecycleListener {

     private static final String FILE = "C:/etc/error.properties";

     public void preStart(ApplicationLifecycleEvent evt) {
        System.out.println("\n\n\t\tInside preStart() method\n\n");
        InputStream is = 
        evt.getApplicationContext().getAppClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(FILE);
        try {
            Properties convertedProps = 
                       convertStreamToProperties(is);
            String userMissingError =
                   convertedProps.getProperty("USER_MISSING_ERROR");
            System.out.println("\n\n\t\tuserMissingError = " 
            + userMissingError + "\n\n");
        } catch (Throwable e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
        }
     }

     public Properties convertStreamToProperties(InputStream is) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("\n\n\t\tInside convertStreamToProperties() method\n\n");
        Properties props = new Properties();
        if (is == null) {
          throw new FileNotFoundException("property file '" + FILE + "' not found");
        } else {
          props.load(is);
          return props;
        }
     }

 }
```

Inside PropertiesDemoEAR/EarContent/META-INF/weblogic-application.xml

I added the following listener declaratively:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wls:weblogic-application 
         xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application" >
    <!--weblogic-version:10.3.5-->
    <wls:application-param>
        <wls:param-name>webapp.encoding.default</wls:param-name>
        <wls:param-value>UTF-8</wls:param-value>
    </wls:application-param>

    <wls:listener>              
         <wls:listener-class>
         com.project.util.PropertiesFileHandler
         </wls:listener-class>
    </wls:listener>
</wls:weblogic-application>
```

Right clicked on the PropertiesDemoEAR / Export / EAR file / Destination:

C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\MyDomain\autodeploy

When I run WebLogic 11g through Eclipse, I get this error message in the console:

```
 [ERROR] AdapterManager - ServletContainerAdapter manager not initialized correctly.
 <oracle.tip.adapter.apps.AppsConnectionFactory> 
 ConnectionManager cm: weblogic.connector.outbound.ConnectionManagerImpl@12433e7-eis/Apps/Apps        
 ManagedConnectionFactory mcf:   
 oracle.tip.adapter.apps.AppsManagedConnectionFactory@4303022b
 <Jun 30, 2011 5:50:24 PM PDT> <Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149265> 
 <Failure occurred in the execution of deployment request 
  with ID '1309481424487' for task '0'. Error is:   
  'weblogic.management.DeploymentException: '
   weblogic.management.DeploymentException: at
   weblogic.application.internal.flow.
   BaseLifecycleFlow$CreateListenerAction.run(BaseLifecycleFlow.java:176) at
   weblogic.security.acl.internal.
   AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321) at 
   weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120) at
   weblogic.application.internal.flow.
   BaseLifecycleFlow$BaseAction.invoke(BaseLifecycleFlow.java:104) at   
   weblogic.application.internal.
   flow.HeadLifecycleFlow.createListener(HeadLifecycleFlow.java:117)
   Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace

   Caused By: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 

   com.project.util.PropertiesFileHandler 

   at weblogic.utils.classloaders.
   GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:297)
```

Question(s):

(1) What am I possibly doing wrong? Why can't it find my PropertiesFileHandler class?

(2) Is the location (c:/etc/error.properties) of my properties file suitable or should it be inside MyDomain directory?

(3) Is there a default directory or just simple configuration area that WebLogic loads properties files which are accessible to any application that runs in WebLogic?

Comment: From my perspective it seems that you are significantly over-complicating the problem.  Are you just trying to get preStart() to work, or are there specific requirements that you have to make it work this way?

Comment: Do you really want to tie the way that you load properties in your application to the way that WebLogic handles the EJB lifecycle, or is this purely an academic exercise?

Comment: No, this is a real professional task... We have a bunch of different app servers and we are seeing the best way to deploy an EAR file which would read different properties files from different app servers. Not the same properties file is used by all. It might have the same name but different contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working... The issue was that I had it set up as Web Project rather than a Java EE Utility Project in Oracle Enterprise Edition for Eclipse.

As a web project, it was putting .class files inside WEB-INF/classes instead of APP-INF.

Also, needed to put error.properties inside my actual domain.

C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\MyDomain

In regards to my own question:

Is there a default directory or just simple configuration area that WebLogic loads properties files which are accessible to any application that runs in WebLogic?

If -Dweblogic.ext.dirs is not set, it defaults to $DOMAIN/lib;$WL_HOME/common/lib/ext;$WL_HOME/server/lib/ext

So if you store error.properties in $DOMAIN/lib it will be on the CLASSPATH and you should be able to load it using getResourceAsStream("error.properties")

Answer (score 1):

Try making sure that the class is in the /lib folder for the machine where the application is being deployed.