# Weblogic 10.3 cannot find external properties file

Tags: spring, weblogic, classpath

I have tried [DeploymentException & Class Not Found on WebLogic Admin Server 11g](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6551464/deploymentexception-class-not-found-on-weblogic-admin-server-11g) among other examples, but I have not been able to get Spring to read external properties file.

I have this code, which read a properties file. Putting the file (PROPERTIES_FILES) in src/main/resources, the app i deployed fine. Moving it to an external folder in the file system, it failes to deploy.

I tried http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-print-out-the-current-project-classpath/ to pribt the classpaths and get:

```
/C:/Oracle/Middleware/patch_wls1034/profiles/default/sys_manifest_classpath/weblogic_patch.jar
/C:/Oracle/Middleware/patch_oepe1040/profiles/default/sys_manifest_classpath/weblogic_patch.jar     /C:/Oracle/Middleware/patch_ocp360/profiles/default/sys_manifest_classpath/weblogic_patch.jar
/C:/Oracle/Middleware/jdk160_21/lib/tools.jar
/C:/Oracle/Middleware/wlserver_10.3/server/lib/weblogic_sp.jar
/C:/Oracle/Middleware/wlserver_10.3/server/lib/weblogic.jar
/C:/Oracle/Middleware/modules/features/weblogic.server.modules_10.3.4.0.jar
/C:/Oracle/Middleware/wlserver_10.3/server/lib/webservices.jar
/C:/Oracle/Middleware/modules/org.apache.ant_1.7.1/lib/ant-all.jar
/C:/Oracle/Middleware/modules/net.sf.antcontrib_1.1.0.0_1-0b2/lib/ant-contrib.jar
/C:/Oracle/Middleware/wlserver_10.3/common/derby/lib/derbyclient.jar
/C:/Oracle/Middleware/wlserver_10.3/server/lib/xqrl.jar

Trying to read test.properties
Found false
Could not find properties file: test.properties
```

My implementation looks like this:

```
    ClassLoader cl = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();

    URL[] urls = ((URLClassLoader)cl).getURLs();

    for(URL url: urls){
        logger.debug(url.getFile());
    }

    logger.debug("Trying to read {}", PROPERTIES_FILES);
    Resource resource = new ClassPathResource(PROPERTIES_FILES);
    logger.debug("Found {}", resource.exists());
    try {
        props = PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadProperties(resource);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error("Could not find properties file: " + PROPERTIES_FILES, e);
    }
```

I have the same problem to move another properties file from in servlet-dispatcher:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:test.properties"/>
```

But I guess it's the same problem.
I am on Windows.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: where exactly on file system is test.properties? Is that folder part of the classpath?

Comment: Sorry for no follow ups, I found that OEPE did not reload classpath. Did a full system restart and it worked. Gotta love Windows!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did a full system restart and it worked.

Comment: That sounds like an Oracle product.